# why kerberos require computer clock synchronization?

Tags: security, kerberos

the client node clock is deliberately set to 10 hours head of kdc

then run **kinit** and **klist** from client node

kinit does not complain,and klist can see the Ticket cache

```
~date -s 19:20:38

~kinit -kt  /etc/kuduclient.keytab kuduclient@EXAMPLE.COM

~klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:0:0
Default principal: kuduclient@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
11/11/2020 09:49:23  11/12/2020 09:11:00  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
    renew until 11/18/2020 09:11:00
```

Comment: isn't the kinit supposed to fail when the time diff exceed minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Time in Kerberos is relative. First, it's supposed to be based on the UTC time zone. If the 10 hour difference is just time-zone related, then the Kerberos stack will happily convert to UTC and all is well.

Second, many (most?) Kerberos stacks don't care about exact time, they care about the time relative to when the KDC thinks it is. What I mean by this is, the client can make a request to the KDC, and if the time is significantly out, the KDC will return an error including what *it* thinks is the current time. The client is free to resend the request with it's time augmented to be within the KDC's window. This still guarantees security correctness because the time constraints are still met from the perspective of the authority -- the KDC.